# Stopping never ending QGIS processes instead of forcing QGIS to quit?

Tags: qgis, osx

being a new to using QGIS on an iMac I often start processes on a large data-set that sets the spinning wheel in to a never ending state.
I often need to force quit the whole QGIS program to break free.

Is there a way to interrupt the processes that I have set in train instead of doing a 'force quit' of QGIS? ...maybe using the osx command line in Terminal?

I am using QGIS 3.4.2 on iMac 10.14.2.

Comment: What if you switch to a blank project instead of quitting QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of the operating system there is a task manager in QGIS 3:

[image]

for more information, see this video by the developer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evuV-etLv-4

Beyond that, I don't think there is a way to kill QGIS-internal processes using operating system tools.

Comment: The Task Manager Does not appear most of the time and does not kill processes a lot of time even if it appears. For example if you mistakenly load a large WFS layer, no way to end the process.